# Running multiple producer and single consumer in a multithread environment

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, producer-consumer

I have a below class in which **`add`** method will be called by multiple threads to populate **`messageByChannelReference`** concurrent hash map in a thread safe way.

For each **`Channel`**, I will have list of **`Message`** object and I want to process all these channels in parallel. And that is why I am using thread safe data structures **`ConcurrentHashMap`** and **`ConcurrentLinkedQueue`**. Here **`Channel`** is an enum in my code.

In the same class, I have a background thread which runs every 30 seconds and it calls **`sendAll`** method which processes multiple channels in parallel so basically idea is I want to send every 30 seconds whatever is there in the map.

```
public class Processor {
  private final ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors
      .newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
  // creating a ListeningExecutorService (Guava) by wrapping a normal ExecutorService (Java)
  private final ListeningExecutorService executor = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(Executors
      .newCachedThreadPool());        
  private final AtomicReference<ConcurrentHashMap<Channel, ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Message>>> messageByChannelReference =
                new AtomicReference<>(new ConcurrentHashMap<Channel, ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Message>>());

  private Processor() {
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        sendAll();
      }
    }, 0, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  // called only by single background thread
  private void sendAll() {  
    ConcurrentHashMap<Channel, ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Message>> messageByChannels = messageByChannelReference
                        .getAndSet(new ConcurrentHashMap<Channel, ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Message>>());           

    List<ListenableFuture<Void>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Entry<Channel, ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Message>> entry : messageByChannels
        .entrySet()) {
      final Channel channel = entry.getKey();
      final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Message> messages = entry.getValue();
      ListenableFuture<Void> future = executor.submit(new Callable<Void>() {
        public Void call() throws Exception {
          send(channel, messages);
          return null;
        }
      });
      list.add(future);
    }

    ListenableFuture<List<Void>> combinedFutures = Futures.allAsList(list);
    try {
      List<Void> allChannels = combinedFutures.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
      Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
      // log error
    }
  }

  private void send(final Channel channel, final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Message> messages) {
    while (!messages.isEmpty()) {
      Message message = messages.poll();
      // ....
      // process this and send to database
    }
  }

  // called by multiple threads to populate the map
  public void add(final Channel channel, final Message message) {
    ConcurrentMap<Channel, ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Message>> messageHolderByChannel =
        messageByChannelReference.get();
    ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Message> messageHolder = messageHolderByChannel.get(channel);
    if (messageHolder == null) {
      messageHolder = Queues.newConcurrentLinkedQueue();
      ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Message> currentMessageHolder =
          messageHolderByChannel.putIfAbsent(channel, messageHolder);
      if (currentMessageHolder != null)
        messageHolder = currentMessageHolder;
    }
    messageHolder.add(message);
  }
}
```

---

**Question:**

My problem is multiple producers and single consumer where multiple producer threads will call `add` method to populate my CHM map. And then I have a single background thread which is my consumer which will read data from this map and work on multiple channels in parallel.

Is this the right way to execute multiple channels in parallel? Let me know if I have missed any thread safety or any race conditions in my code.
I don't need to block in my case, if queue is empty, I will return back and start again after 30 seconds. Right now I have a `Void` on callable but I will change that to Boolean in future.

I am working with Java 7.

Comment: Might be a better fit for code review stack exchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's tackle the Threading and synchronization. It's a big task.

### Just one word before hand: [Immutability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) is the king synchronization.

Just putting objects in Thread-safe Java Collections does not protect the *Objects*. It only protects the `Collection`'s functionality from Threading shenanigans (inserting, retrieving, removing will all keep the Collection in a valid state, but the Objects can be used and treated asynchronously).

---

### AtomicReference

Its purpose is to hold an editable reference, in a way that any observer at any time see the most up-to-date reference. I.e., *while* someone edits the reference using `set()`, no thread can use get() and obtain a wrong reference (Without synchronization, it could either obtain the old one, the new one, a null bogus ref, etc.). In fact, if you look at its source, it is just a `volatile` holder. Its is handy when you need to edit a reference...

But you never do it!

So you can just **drop it**, and simply make `messageByChannelReference` an immutable (`final`, because it effectively is) `ConcurrentHashMap`. As a bonus we get rid of one `AtomicReference<...>` Layer, because those `<>` really started to stack up!

---

### `ConcurrentHashMap`

In the same vein, `ConcurrentHashMap` protects its mapping so that it still holds when it is updated asynchronously. But not the keys, nor the values, are pretected from being *used* (i.e. methods invoked) asynchronously. Now, if you're using a *Concurrent* map, you're expecting somthing to change the *mapping* Channel --> Queue.

Your `Channel`s are a constant (they are in an enum). So you never modify the Map's keys.  The keys point to some `Queues`. Why drop the queues? Why not empty their content? Would you throw away your glass when you drank all the wine it contained? I wouldn't - I usually reuse my glass. So you can keep the Queue reference in place.

If you never change the *mapping*, you don't need a Concurrent Map, [you need an *immutable* one](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html), so you mustfind another implmentation. Thankfully you're already using Guava :D.

Just a word: to make the Map immutable, you have to fill it with data first. That means instancing all Queues from the start. I see you've lazily initialized those. [Lazy initialisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization) is not *always* of any benefit, but is always resulting in obfuscated code (with lots if `if(a=null)a=new A();`). I recommend dropping the laziness here, as a few `Queue` references won't hurt anyone.

Quick recap: I'proposing that you replace:

```
private final AtomicReference<ConcurrentHashMap<Channel, ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Message>>> messageByChannelReference = new AtomicReference<>(new ConcurrentHashMap<Channel, ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Message>>());
```

By:

```
private final ImmutableMap<Channel, ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Message>>> messageByChannel;
private Processor(){
    // ...Other stuff...
    ImmutableMap.Builder<Channel, ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Message>>> mapBuilder = ImmutableMap.Builder();
    for(Channel channel : Channel.getEnumConstants()){
        mapBuilder.put(channel, new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Message>());
    }
    this.messageByChannel = mapBuilder.build();
}
```

---

### What *needs* to be Thread safe, then?

Well, anything that is *modified* asynchronously (as we've seen, this excluded the Map reference, and the Map itself).

The messages are *added to the queues* asynchronously. So those queues must be made Thread safe. And they are! So... we're good, I think.

---

### How does it work now?

You build a map, assign queues to Channels, then start all Threads.

A thread comes up to the map asking for a Queue to put his  payload...
...The map returns the corresponding Queue (there's only one, ts mapping never changes, there's never a mistake to be made)...
...The Thread puts his Message in that Queue (The Queue is Thread safe, so it isn't *broken* by this unexpected action)...
...then continues its business.

From time to time an Executor Thread pops up...
...browses each of the Map's Queues (safely, no changes to the map or to the mapping)...
... And proceed to take (`poll`) messages, *one-by-one* (safely, those poll() are made on a Concurrent Queues)...
...and processes them.

Now, it's important to read the [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html)'s Javadoc, because a few points are important:

- It is a **thread-safe queue** (good)
- It **does not permit the use of null elements** (didn't see much null-checks! Some are required, maybe)
- Its **Iterators are *weakly* consistent** (this is why I recommend using poll() repeatedly. poll() is guaranteed to never give the same object to two Threads at the same time)

---

### Add Messages **(Edit)**

The method does not change much. One warning: do not call a `Collection` a `Holder`. Usually a `Holder` holds a *singleton*, like a wrapper for a piece of data or a reference.

```
// (Assuming messageByChannel is the map)
public void add(final Channel channel, final Message message) {
    messageByChannel.get(channel).add(message); // That's it!
    // No need for null-checking, we did the Queue instancing manually in Constructor
}
```

---

### Send the messages: Which Thread? **(Edit)**

Right now the Executor Threads calls `sendAll()` on concurrent `Future`s, then halts. I don't really see why the Executor Threads couldn't prepare and send backages *itself*?

Like:

```
private void sendAll() {  
    for (Entry<Channel, ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Message>> entry : messageByChannels.entrySet()) {
        final Channel channel = entry.getKey();
        final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Message> messages = entry.getValue();
        send(channel, messages);
    }
}
private void send(final Channel channel, final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Message> messages) {
    Message message;
    while (message = messages.poll()  != null) { // don't use isEmpty without synchronizing, the message could be gone between isEmpty() and poll() calls!
        // ....
        // process this and send to database
    }
}
```

---

### Send the messages: Channel by Channel **(Edit)**

You stated you want the Channels to be sent asynchronously. You've elected to have one Thread run at intervals from an Executor, which spawns a few sender Threads everytime it runs.

Why not directly schedule one job per Channel? This way, you could interrupt one temporarily in production, or add more, or adjust the sending rate *per channel*.

**(Edit 2)** Here's how to do it from the `Processor` class :

```
private static final ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
private static final int POLLING_DELAY = 30;
private Processor() {
    int staggerDelay = 1 + POLLING_DELAY  / Channel.values().length;
    int channelNum = 0;
    for(Channel channel : Channel.getEnumConstants()){
        executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                sendChannel(targetChannel);
            }
        }, channelNum * staggerDelay++, POLLING_DELAY, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

The `send(Channel, Queue)` method parameters are redundant, since the queues are uniquely assigned to the Channels (the mapping info is constant). I rewrote it as:

```
private void sendChannel(final Channel channel) {
    ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Message> messages = messageByChannels.get(channel);
    Message message;
    while ((message = messages.poll())  != null) { // Don't use isEmpty without synchronizing, the message could be gone between isEmpty() and poll() calls!
        // ....
        // process this and send to database
    }
}
```

There you go, you have one polling job per Channel (polling adjustable), and the provider Threads. No otherThreads needed. The executor service is still available to manage those jobs. I staggered the Polling Thread starts to prevent bottlenecking. Of course the `sendChannel` could be made smarter (like using batching etc.) but that is for later.

Comment: Thanks for your great feedback so in short I can drop atomic reference and use final concurrent hash map directly and then my add method  will be modified accordingly as well right? Also in your usage example, you didn't mentioned about executing multiple channels in parallel? In my case, I want to execute multiple channels in parallel so whatever  I am doing in my code is right and I should continue to use that? Or maybe I understood it wrong?

Comment: The hashmap doesn't need to be concurrent, I suggested an immutable map. The add method doesn't need much change (tho it must compile ^^) except to drop `putIfAbsent` thanks to the non-lazy init. For parallel channel polling I'll edit my answer later.

Comment: @user1950349 clarified Immutable map, added updated `add` function, and proposed Parallel Channel polling. Is that clear enough?

Comment: Yeah understood most of the things and looks very neat. Few follow up questions though: 1) Do I need both classes now - `Processor` and `Channel` as looks like you have mixed these two? In my case `Channel` was just simply an enum and `Processor` class I was using to populate message object for each channel and then in the same class I was starting a background thread to send all the messages for each channels.

Comment: Since after looking your `Channel` class, you are starting a background thread over there only and withn `sendChannel` method you use `messageByChannels` map which is defined in processor class so got confuse slightly. 2) If we just need one class, then what's the name of the class I should use which depicts the behavior that class is doing. 3) Also then `add` method will go to Enum as well (assuming we keep only enum class) if we decide to use one class?

Comment: Oh yeah didn't spot I was using that method from Processor, my bad I got carried away. And no, don't fuse classes it's almost always a bad idea. Just put thread creation back in Processor, and iterate over the enum. I'll edit my post again.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense now. One thing I noticed when I was trying it out - On this line `while (message = messages.poll()  != null) {`, it gives me compilation error as `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Message to boolean`. What's wrong here? I think it will be like this `while ((message = messages.poll())  != null) {`. Correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53287/discussion-between-user1950349-and-sylvain-boisse).

Comment: yeah it makes sense what you said in the chat. Also since it is single thread executor will it start all channel background thread to process the channel independently (after stagger delay) or it will wait for one channel to finish and then it will work on other channel, and then other channel like that?

Comment: Yeah, change the executor to a pooled one. As it is It won't work

Comment: Yup did that.. One last question hopefully, In the constructor of `Processor` class you have `channelNum` initialized to zero and for all the channels it gets used as 0 only. Do I need to increment that for each channel to get initial delay for all those channels? Because right now, it uses same `initialDelay` in the `scheduleAtFixedRate` for all the channels I guess?

Comment: @SylvainBoisse I also have similar question related to multithreading [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/183312/send-data-on-a-socket-from-multiple-threads) so wanted to see if you can help me out there if possible.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 things that I am primarily concerned with here:

1. `messageByChannelReference`
2. `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` inside of a `ConcurrentHashMap`

---

**Problem with #1**

As I have interpreted your code, you seem to want to discard the current current hashmap and populate an empty one every time you send all the messages. However, the problem is that whenever you decide to sendAll, you must iterate over the entry set of a map that will be discarded. You may still maintain a reference of the discarded map whilst you are iterating over the weakly consistent entry set view. This means that you could have discarded the old map while still adding entries to it, and your iterator may not see those entries because it is [weakly consistent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#entrySet()).

---

**Problem with #2**

From what I understand, you are creating a lookup table (cache) that creates new entries if they do not already exist. This isn't necessarily a problem here, but I think that you have needlessly created a complicated tree of entries that can be vastly simplified and in fact not have to create a new linked queue that might be thrown away if the method loses the race.

Side note: I embarrassingly became confused due to the lack of computeIfAbsent before I realized that you needed to use Java 7.

---

**How do you fix it**

The solution is very simple, wrap both your Channel and the Message together in an immutable object and place it in a ConcurrentLinkedQueue. This will solve both of the aforementioned problems. The way I see it being implemented:

```
private final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<QueuedMessage> messages = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

public void sendAll() {
    QueuedMessage m;
    while ((m = messages.poll()) != null) {
        // ...
        send(m.getChannel(), m.getPayload());
        // ...
    }
}

public void add(Channel ch, Message payload) {
    messages.offer(new QueuedMessage(ch, payload));
}

class QueuedMessage {
    private final Channel channel;
    private final Message payload;
    public QueuedMessage(Channel ch, Message payload) {
        channel = ch;
        this.payload = payload;
    }

    // Getters
}
```

As you can see, much simpler, thread-safe, less esoteric and easier to read.

Comment: This is cleaner, but it lacks one functionality. OP provided code that allowed Channels to be emptied *asychonously*. In your solution, channels are mixed up, and sent all at once.

Comment: That's why I added the ..., I mean that OP can use what I provided as a starting point to add what functionality they need.